# How can I add a function of time requested previously as input in ODE 45? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, physics

I'm having this problem: Let's suposse that a user wants to add an arbitrary Force (a function of time) to a spring mass damper system. In order to do that, we request the force as an input, i.e. F = cos(t). Well, I noticed that if we add a function of time in the code where the **F** is placed (inside **ODE**), then the solutions for the movement equations are correct. But i can't find a way to achieve this goal. I mean, to request the force as input so that ODE changes everytime i put a new force. I've tried almost everything like converting the input F to a function, etc.

I hope you could help me.  Here is the problem in the code:

```
F   = input('Insert force F(t)..............[N] = ','s'); 

u0  = [x0,v0];                                            % INITIAL CONDITIONS AS A VECTOR

ODE = @(t,u) [u(2) ; F - (c/m)*u(2) - (k/m)*u(1)];        % FORCED SPRING MASS DAMPER SYSTEM

[t,u] = ode45(ODE, [0 tf], u0);
```

The fix code results:

```
m   = input('Insert mass of the system..........................[kg] = ');
c   = input('Insert viscosity coefficient........................[ ] = ');
k   = input('Insert elasticity constant..........................[m] = ');
x0  = input('Insert initial position.............................[m] = ');
v0  = input('Insert initial velocity...........................[m/s] = ');
tf  = input('Insert time of complete movement....................[s] = ');
F   = input('Insert external force as F(t).......................[N] = ','s');

F = str2func( ['@(t)' F] );                    % CONVERT STRING TO FUNCTION

%=========================================================== ODE 45 =======
u0 = [x0,v0];                              % INITIAL CONDITIONS AS A VECTOR

ODE  = @(t,u) [u(2) ; F(t) - (c/m)*u(2) - (k/m)*u(1)];
[t,u] = ode45(ODE, [0 tf], u0);

u(:,3) = F(t) - (c/m)*u(:,2) - (k/m)*u(:,1);                 % ACCELERATION

%============================================================= PLOT =======
v = {'x','dx/dt','d2x/dt2'};                         % CHAR VECTOR FOR PLOT

for i = 1:3                                                % PLOT WITH LOOP
    subplot(3,1,i)
    plot(t,u(:,i));
    xlabel('t');
    ylabel(v(i));
    grid on;
end
```

*Code just for personal uses. Not public because input allows malicious commands.*

Thanks to @Wolfie and @Ander Biguri.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to be able to have a F that changes? does it need to come from `input` ?

Comment: Hi Ander! What would you suggested instead of using input.? I just wanted the user to write the force down (as a function of t) every time he runs the script.

Comment: Its OK, but the way you do it `F` is a string, not an equation. So you need a way to add a string into that function.

Comment: Exactly. I tried to declare syms t before the inputs, transform F to a function of t using str2func(['@(x) ' F]);. I've also tried to put F as a string and then cited it as char(F) inside ODE. Also other kind of combinations but i can't find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take the liberty of simplifying your problem down to its main parts.

1. You have some char array from your user `input` which defines a function in terms of `t`. I'm going to entirely ignore all the reasons that blindly evaluating user-input functions is dangerous, but you shouldn't.
2. You want to combine this function with an existing function in terms of `t` to produce a single function

We can do this like so:

```
F = 'cos(t)'; % char version of function, e.g. from the input command
y = @(t) t;   % some base function in terms of t

F = str2func( ['@(t)' F] ); % Convert function char to anonymous function

yF = @(t) y(t) + F(t); % combine the functions
```

You can test this with a quick plot

```
tt = 0:0.01:10; % axis data
figure; hold on;
plot( tt, y(tt),  'displayname', 'y(t)'  );
plot( tt, yF(tt), 'displayname', 'yF(t)' );
legend('show');
```

[image: plot]

In your actual example you have `ODE` in place of my example `f`, so  assuming `F` is converted to an anonymous function as shown above, you would get

```
ODE = @(t,u) [u(2) ; F(t) - (c/m)*u(2) - (k/m)*u(1)];
```

Comment: Hi Wolfie! Thank you so much for the explanation. That's the correct answer. I was so close when i tried to solved this little inconvenient.  I used F = str2func( ['@(t)' F] ), but I didn't realized that i should have written F(t) inside ODE. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Indeed, by including the `(t)` within the function, you are instructing MATLAB to actually *evaluate* `F` for the given `t`

Comment: @NicolasPereyra I suggest that you do not use this for "public use". The first point of Wolfie says something about safety. If someone inputs a malicious command as input, you will evaluate it.